# Accidently moved /* into another folder while in single user mode

Tags: macos, bash, osx-mavericks

My laptop has a bad gpu and while attempting to move AMD and ATI kext's out of /System/Library/Extensions I accidentally issued:

mv /System/Library/Extensions/AMD * /Disabled_Extensions.

The extra space before the * caused / to move into /Disabled_Extensions, now when I try to use mv or ls I get a -sh: /Disabled_Extensions/bin/mv: No such file or directory. My best guess is it's happening because mv is linked to a library that has been moved.

I've tried exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH but this does not seem to be how osx does things.  I'm still in single user mode and in a bash shell, anyone know what I can do to move this stuff back?

Comment: Are you sure `/Disabled_Extensions/bin/mv` exists (or existed, before you fixed it)? Hint: even when you can't run `ls`, you can list a directory with `echo *`.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two potential fixes.

Simple (if it works):

```
/Disabled_Extensions/bin/ln -s /Disabled_Extensions/* /
cp -p /Disabled_Extensions/* / # Doing a copy instead of a move in case it doesn't work, and we don't want to split your data
```

With the above, you'll also have everything that was originally in /System/Library/Extensions/AMD in your root, so you'll have a bit of cleaning up to do afterwards.

More complicated (but should be successful):

Boot into rescue mode using your distribution CD/DVD or a Live CD (Knoppix, for example), mount your filesystem(s), and move your data back where it belongs.

Edit: Replaced "." at the end of the ln line with "/" in case you're not already in the root directory.

Comment: Unfortunatly /Disabled_Extensions/bin/ln and ./Disabled_Extensions/bin/ln gives a -sh: /Disabled_Extensions/bin/ln: No such file or directory as well.  And so does trying to start bash and sh. Going to try the live cd route if all else fails, though I I'll have use a usb stick.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this by using another mac to create Mint based live usb (using http://sevenbits.github.io/Mac-Linux-USB-Loader/) and then mounting the broken partition and moving things back into place.  The AMD/ATI kext removal also forced my macbook to use intel graphics which is allowing it to work for now.